# Regex that returns words, including words that contain numbers but not words that are just numbers

Tags: regex

More specifically it cannot return words that are **just numbers** or contain any other characters such as `#$.,` etc characters with accents are fine.

So if I use this text as an example:

> we bought 6 500ml beers for $ 6.00 each from the êcole bar

would return  `we bought 500ml beers for each from the êcole bar` so it removed the `6` and  `$` and the `6.00`

In short; I am trying to read the item name from a restaurant receipt while ignoring the price and quantity of items being bought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a regex like

```
/([0-9]+)?[a-zA-Zê]/
```

Answer (score -1):

To match all words with no digits use

> /\b[^\d\W]+\b/g

To skip words which constists of only digits use

```
(?!^\d+$)^.+$
```

Comment: It needs to return words that contain digits too, like "500ml"