# Regex to return integers only without surrounding letters or decimals

Tags: regex, swift

As the question says so that in the following string:

```
"2 x 500ml 1664 êcole beer £8.0"
```

i would  get `2` and `1664` returned only.

Ive tried: `[1-9][0-9]*` which is close but returns the 500 in 500ml and the 8 in #8.0

The idea is to return the quantity when reading a line in a receipt, hence the example above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get numbers from string with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243447/get-numbers-from-string-with-php). Also, what have you tried? There's surely a better duplicate out there, but this is the one I found with little research

Comment: Didn't you just ask a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46424370/6124528?

Comment: I'd suggest you learn regex. As @Manav pointed out, you're asking a few regex questions that a very similar. While the stackoverflow is more than willing to help you, we are not a coding service to write your code for you.

Comment: Yes, but im looking to get just the integers. From here i can get the first integer which would more than likely be a quantity

Comment: Hi you're right i do need to. But ive just been unsuccesful for a while now. I feel its better to learn this in my free time though.

Comment: There's no clear-cut way to get just integers when you're talking about multiple possible strings. If you present us with a multitude of strings and the values you want, we can probably get them for you. For example, if you have a string of `This is number 1. This is number 2.` - do we need to parse this? Is this a possible string? According to what you've presented, you need this regex: `(?<=\s|^)(\d+)(?=\s|$)` but this will only work for specific strings (such as the one you presented). It's also important to specify the language you are using since each language has different regex support

Comment: The best way might be to split the string by space and remove all non-digit characters and then, with code, determine whether or not they are integers, floats, etc.

Comment: Right ok, im using swift. And the idea is to get a quantity from reading a line in a receipt which is normally the first integer.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Python**, I would try to get the each number separately like this:

---

**First occurrence:**

```
"(\d{+})\ x"
```

[image]

---

**Second occurrence:**

```
"\ (\d{4})\ "
```

[image]

Now you'll just have to find a way to get the numbers that are inside each group.. ;-)

---

**EDIT:**

You can get the numbers using a one-line solution, and then fetch each subgroup to access the numbers.

**One-line Solution:**

```
"(\d+)\ "
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't `\d{1}` sort of redundant? Also, why don't you create a one-liner

Comment: You're correct! But since I'm mostly a python programmer I prefer to let things very explicit.. :P

Comment: About the one-line solution, can you show us how we could achieve this?

Comment: `\d|\d{4}`, but realistically you should use `\d+` since there is potentially a possibility of multiple digit numbers like `10 x ...`, etc.

Comment: Good point! Changed `"(\d{1})\ x"` to `"(\d{+})\ x"`. Also added `"(\d+)\ "` as a one-line solution based on your comment. Thanks.